# Servlet failed to verify the received Google Sign-In token

Tags: google-signin, google-oauth

I am developing a **Java servlet & JSP** based web application.  I would like to
support users to login through Google Sign-In.  I copy the sample JSP code
obtained from the Internet to bring up the Google Sign-In page.  After the
user sign-in successfully, the Javascript code sends the token to the servlet.
The servlet then uses the following code to verify the token received:

```
public static GoogleIdToken.Payload getPayload (String tokenString) throws Exception {
     GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier =
         new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory())
     .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID))
     .build();
     Payload payload = null;
     GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(tokenString);
     if (idToken != null) {
        payload = idToken.getPayload();
        String userId = payload.getSubject();
        System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);
        // Get profile information from payload
        String email = payload.getEmail();
        boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
        String name = (String) payload.get("name");
     } // of if (idToken != null)
     return payload;
  }
```

However, the code `verifier.verify(...)` always results in the following exception:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
>       java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
>       java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
>       java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>       java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>       java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>       java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>       java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>       java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>       sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
>       sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
>       sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
>       sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
>       sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:264)
>       sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
>       sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
>       sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
>       sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
>       sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
>       sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
>       com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
>       com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
>       com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GooglePublicKeysManager.refresh(GooglePublicKeysManager.java:172)
>       com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GooglePublicKeysManager.getPublicKeys(GooglePublicKeysManager.java:141)
>       com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier.verify(GoogleIdTokenVerifier.java:174)
>       com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier.verify(GoogleIdTokenVerifier.java:192)

I could not figure out why.  Can some one help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I copied the token verification code to a Console program and run it on a local machine.  The code works as expected.  So, the connection timeout exception is due to network settings problem.  The outgoing connection to Google server is actually blocked!